# Shortcut to hide single window of an application?

Tags: shortcut

Mac has a shortcut command + H to hide all the windows of an application. Is there a shortcut, or a way to create a shortcut, to hide just the current window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the closest you get is Window->Minimize: <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Technically, macOS hides **the application**, not "all its windows". The app's menubar is also gone.

There doesn't appear to be a "Hide" ***function*** for a given window, and certainly no menu command, nor AppleScript command to do so.

You can Minimize a window, of course, using the orange button. There isn't always a menu command for this (depending on the app: some have only "Minimize All"); and no AppleScript either.

However, there are all kinds of other things you can do with Mission Control and <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>`</kbd>, so you might want to consider alternative workflows to help you with whatever it is that you want to hide a window for.